# Deploying asp.net application to eucalyptus cloud

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, cloud, eucalyptus

I have a web application in visual studio 2010 and I have created a private cloud using eucalyptus on centos.Is it possible to deploy my application on this cloud?